# Does the axiom of choice holds in $L(\mathcal{P}(\lambda))$?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

[Cantor's Attic](http://web.archive.org/web/20191005075514/http://cantorsattic.info/Constructible_universe#Sharps) claimed the following:

> However, Shelah proved that if λ is a strong limit cardinal of uncountable cofinality then $L(\mathcal{P}(\lambda))$ is a model of AC.

If that's because there is a definable global well-order of $L(\mathcal{P}(\lambda))$, it seems to imply that there is a global well-order of $V$, defined by $x \prec y$ if there is a strong limit cardinal of uncountable cofinality $\lambda$ such that $x \in L(\mathcal{P}(\lambda))$ and $y \notin L(\mathcal{P}(\lambda))$ or otherwise $x$ precedes $y$ in the $L(\mathcal{P}(\lambda))$-order, where $\lambda$ is the least strong limit cardinal of uncountable cofinality such that $x \in L(\mathcal{P}(\lambda))$.

**This is too good to be true.** What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the fact that the well-ordering of $\cal P(\lambda)$ is definable from a parameter, but indeed, many different parameters can be used. So in order to choose one for each $\lambda$ of uncountable cofinality, you have to use Global Choice to begin with.

Shelah's theorem really shows that in the presence of $\sf DC$, if $\lambda$ such that $\omega<\operatorname{cf}(\lambda)<\lambda$, then there is some $x$ such that $\cal P(\lambda)\subseteq\mathrm{HOD}_x$. This means that from this one $x$, we get a well-ordering of $\cal P(\lambda)$, and therefore a definable well-ordering of $L(\mathcal P(\lambda))$ *using $x$ as a parameter*. But, as I said, this $x$ is not quite definable in the general case. So in order to get $\sf AC$ you'd need, beyond $\sf DC$, also that you can choose such $x$ uniformly, which is begging the question.

Two relevant papers:

1. *Shelah, Saharon*, [**Set theory without choice: Not everything on cofinality is possible**](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s001530050057), Arch. Math. Logic 36, No. 2, 81-125 (1997). [ZBL0877.03023](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0877.03023).
2. *Cummings, James; Friedman, Sy-David; Magidor, Menachem; Rinot, Assaf; Sinapova, Dima*, [**Ordinal definable subsets of singular cardinals**](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s11856-018-1712-2), Isr. J. Math. 226, No. 2, 781-804 (2018). [ZBL1436.03259](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1436.03259).

Comment: I didn't know more about Shelah's theorem than I quoted in my question.

Comment: More specifically, the parameter $x$ needed is essentially a set that *witnesses* the hypotheses about $\lambda$, i.e. $x$ encodes a cofinal sequence in $\lambda$ and injections that witness that $2^\kappa<\lambda$ for each $\kappa<\lambda$.

Comment: @ArvidSamuelsson: I figured, otherwise you'd have not asked it.